# How to disable submit in AngularJS in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, ng-file-upload

I am having some trouble with disabling **Submit button** in a HTML form in AngularJS.

**Scenario:**

- I am selecting a certain process from a **HTML Select Box ie. Drop
  Down List**
- Once I select some entry from that, the lower portion is
  automatically populated with the required form which again has a set
  of inputs
- Once you fill in these value, you can either **Submit** or **Cancel** the request

**Condition:**
There is a process in the list where I need to upload 1 or more files along with other input parameters. To do this, I am using a two step approach where I first Choose a File using a button and then I use another button to Upload the file. Clicking on this button makes a REST call and the file is sent to the required target.
I am using `ng-file-upload` directive from https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload to accomplish this.

**Problem:**
I was initially using `ng-disabled`to disable submit button on the condition that ***All mandatory input elements are filled and all input validations are passed***. Now the problem occurs when I am in the use cases which need files to be uploaded. When I choose a file and upload it, HTML treats that element as empty as the file is already sent to its target and hence fails the validation  ***All mandatory input elements are filled***! If I remove this validation, my form expectedly get submitted even if Mandatory fields are empty.

So what can I do in this case to disable my submit button?

Comment: i havent worked on such cases but I think you can assign boolean value as `true` to some variable (say $scope.flag) when the REST service returns success response.On `ng-submit` function , you can check if the `form.$valid` is true and `$scope.flag` is true then submit the form.

Comment: @ShashankVivek I actually tried that. The problem in this case becomes that form.$valid becomes false. And hence the button remains disabled

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable as what @ShashankVivek said.

if file uploaded $scope.uploaded = true.

so your button should look like this

```
<button data-ng-disabled="!form.valid && !uploaded">Submit</button>
```

Comment: what is the difference between ng-disabled and data-ng-disabled?

Comment: @ashhem data-ng-disabled passes through html5 validators better compared to ng-disabled. It's a better practise to use "data-ng" instead of "ng".